# Reference of a Java static method of a type parametrized class in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, static-methods, method-reference

How to write method reference to a Java static method of a generic class in Kotlin?

Example below shows that `::` operator works only in case of non-generic classes (`Colections` in this case). However using the same approach doesn't seem to work for `List` interface that has a type parameter.

```kotlin
import java.util.Collections
import java.util.List

fun toSingletonList(item: Int, toList: (Int) -> MutableList<Int>): MutableList<Int> {
    return toList(item)
}

fun main() {
    println(toSingletonList(1, { Collections.singletonList(it) }))
    println(toSingletonList(1, Collections::singletonList))
    println(toSingletonList(1, { List.of(it) }))
    println(toSingletonList(1, List::of))          // not compilable: One type argument expected for interface List<E : Any!>
    println(toSingletonList(1, List<Int>::of))     // not compilable: Unresolved reference: of
}
```

Comment: Don't use `java.util.List` in Kotlin, `println(toSingletonList(1, ::mutableListOf))`

Comment: `List` was chosen for demo purposes as a well known API, I experienced this problem with a private library that wouldn't be suitable for a code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the `of()` method directly:

```kotlin
import java.util.List.of
```

And then you're able to reference it directly:

```kotlin
println(toSingletonList(1, ::of))
```

If you happen to run into conflicts. E.g. by importing also `Set.of` you may use import aliasing:

```kotlin
import java.util.List.of as jListOf
import java.util.Set.of as jSetOf
```

and then use *that* alias as a method reference

```kotlin
println(toSingletonList(1, ::jListOf))
println(toSingletonSet(1, ::jSetOf))
```

Comment: @lino-vote-dont-say-thanks Does it mean that creation of qualified (without the import, with class name prefix) method reference of static method in generic class is not possible in Kotlin?

Comment: @czerny I can't find a source that confirms it, but I also didn't get it to work. So I would assume that it is not (yet) possible